# Assert interface with nested struct pointer

Tags: pointers, go, interface, nested

I need to assign the struct to an interface{} (a) and then assert it again (b) like in my example. I need MyStruct and MyNestedStruct to be convertible.

https://play.golang.org/p/LSae9dasJI

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debugging your code I arrived at this (still broken state) which clearly shows what is problematic with your implementation; https://play.golang.org/p/MnyDxKvJsK

The second link has the issue resolved. Basically, your type didn't actually implement the interface because of your return type. Yes the return type implements the interface, but it's *not an instance* of the interface. Look closely at the code below;

```
// your version *MyNestedStruct != MyNestedInterface
func (this *MyStruct) GetNested() *MyNestedStruct {
    return this.nested
}

type MyInterface interface{
    GetNested() MyNestedInterface
}

//my version
func (this *MyStruct) GetNested() MyNestedInterface {
    return this.nested
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uf2FfvbATb